# optmize query to get the grand total at the end of the result set in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have a script that produces the following result:

Desired Result Set:
[image]

Here is the query that I used.

```
Select 
        SiteName, 
        (coalesce(country, '') + cast(row_number() over (partition by country order by country) as varchar(255))) Country, 
        Completed, 
        (Total - Completed-Deleted-Rejected) Remaining, 
      Deleted, 
        Total
from dbo.Statistics 
        where Date between '12/10/2016' and '12/29/2016' 
        and SiteName='pcltb.co.in'

union all

select 
        'Total', 
        'Total', 
        sum(Completed), 
        sum((Total - Completed-Deleted-Rejected)), 
        sum(Deleted),
        sum(Total)
from dbo.Statistics 
        where Date between '12/10/2016' and '12/29/2016' 
        and SiteName='pcltb.co.in'
```

Now, in order to optimize the query, I tried using ROLL UP and CUBE but couldn't get the desired results.

PS: I would like a replacement or alternate for UNION used in the query.

Pl advice.

Comment: please avoid using images while showing results ,paste expected result,current result as text

Comment: SQL Server is a Databases Management System best optimised to store and retrieve data, for data presentation we have other reporting tools like SSRS , Qlikview etc, use a proper tool for data presentation SQL Server is not built for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE.

```
with t as (Select 
        SiteName, 
        (coalesce(country, '') + cast(row_number() over (partition by country order by country) as varchar(255))) Country, 
        Completed, 
        (Total - Completed-Deleted-Rejected) Remaining, 
      Deleted, 
        Total
from dbo.Statistics 
        where Date between '12/10/2016' and '12/29/2016' 
        and SiteName='pcltb.co.in')
select * from t
union all
select 'Total', 'Total',
        sum(Completed), 
        sum(Remaining), 
        sum(Deleted),
        sum(Total)
from t group by SiteName, Country;
```

This will read the table once, and apply sum on already computed values.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ;WITH tb(sitename,Country,Complete,Reminning,Deleted,Total)AS
    (
       SELECT 'pcltb.co.in',1,34,0,1,35 UNION
       SELECT 'pcltb.co.in',2,48,0,1,35
    )
    SELECT ISNULL(sitename,'Total') AS sitename,ISNULL(Country,'Total') as Country,SUM(Complete) AS Complete,SUM(Reminning) AS Reminning,SUM(Deleted) AS Deleted,SUM(Total) AS Total 

    FROM tb
    GROUP BY sitename,Country
    WITH ROLLUP
    HAVING GROUPING(sitename)=GROUPING(Country)
```

```
sitename    Country     Complete    Reminning   Deleted     Total
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
pcltb.co.in 1           34          0           1           35
pcltb.co.in 2           48          0           1           35
Total       Total        82          0           2           70
```